# Strange Statement/Exercise about random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

So the statement i don't understand is:

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable, then there exists another (discrete) random variable $X'$ on a probability space with the same distribution.

The only thing that occurs to me is that if i define $X':=X$ , then obviously they have the same distribution. But this just looks too simple.

I hope someone could help me understand/proof the statement

thanks in advance

Comment: Is the statement you're confused by a direct quote? And is there more context?

Comment: No its a Lemma in a script i am reading

Comment: Can you link to the script? (Do you mean paper? I assume this is not a script for a play or anything.)

Comment: Yeah i mistranslated it, i meant lecture notes.